# Trying to create a new file in Bitbucket via a REST API call

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

This is a follow up question to a previous question. I'm trying to write a program in Javascript that receives the contents of a yml file encoded as a string and adds that yml file to a remote BitBucket server repo via a RESTful API query. I've followed the instructions in [this documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/rest/v809/api-group-repository/#api-api-latest-projects-projectkey-repos-repositoryslug-browse-path-put) and I've been able to update an existing file's contents in this way. However, despite the fact that the documentation claims that I should be able to create a new file in the same manner, I haven't been able to do so.

I've left the sourceCommitId blank, as it says to do in the documentation, but it still requires a path to the file that doesn't exist yet. Using the url structure "http://{baseurl}/rest/api/latest/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}" or adding "/browse" to that gets a 405 response. And adding a file name to the end returns a 404 response with the message "filename could not be edited because the file has been deleted on the branch".

The documentation doesn't seem to indicate what should be done when using this method to create a new file in the repo, nor have I been able to find any answers about it in community support pages. Is there anyone who is familiar with this who can tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my issue: the end of the url after "/browse/" should indeed be the file path that you want the new folder to have in your repository. My mistake was that I needed to remove sourceCommitId from the body entirely, add a key called "sourceBranch" and set it to the branch that you want to base your commit off of, and change branch to the name of the branch to you want to add the file to (either an existing one or a new one if you want to create a whole new branch off of your sourceBranch).

So, if I wanted to add a file to a repo called "test123.yml", I would write the url as "http://{baseurl}/rest/api/latest/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/browse/test123.yml". Then I would set up the body like this:

```
{
  "branch": "new-branch",
  "content": "This is the contents of the new file",
  "message": "This is the commit message",
  "sourceBranch": "old-branch",
}
```